# How to use @@ROWCOUNT in IF statement as well as within BEGIN..END block?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

My code is as follows:

```
SET @var = (SELECT var FROM dbo.varDB WHERE varName = @varName)

IF (@@ROWCOUNT > 0)
    BEGIN
        //carry out insert
    END
```

Am I right in saying this will always return a *1* for *@@ROWCOUNT* as it carries out an assignment last?

If so, what would be the most elegant solution to allow me to:

- Create variable with the result from my query stored in it
- Test if the query returns any results

Comment: Have you tried the above set statement when there are 0, 1 and more than one matching rows?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason it returns one is because you've assigned exactly one value (some arbitrary value). You should be using `EXISTS` instead of doing a manual count anyway, as @Sive suggests. The reason is that EXISTS can perform no worse than COUNT, and in the use case you're describing, it doesn't really matter what the actual count is anyway. You want to know if the count is zero or greater than zero.

The problem with assigning that value to a variable in the way you've done it, is what happens if there are multiple rows that match? Let's try it:

```
DECLARE @foo TABLE([var] INT, varname SYSNAME);
INSERT @foo VALUES (1,N'bob'),(2,N'bob');
DECLARE @var INT;
SET @var = (SELECT [var] FROM @foo WHERE varname = N'bob
```

Result:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 4 
> Subquery returned more than 1
>   value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Now, if `varname` is unique, I would do this:

```
SELECT @var = [var] FROM dbo.varDB WHERE varName = @varName;
IF @var IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    // carry out insert
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Already existed! ' + RTRIM(@var);
END
```

If `varname` is *not* unique, then I'm not sure what you're going to do with a single value. Which one did it pull? Imagine this scenario:

```
DECLARE @foo TABLE([var] INT, varname SYSNAME);
INSERT @foo VALUES (3,N'bob'),(2,N'adam'),(1,N'bob');
DECLARE @var INT;
SELECT @var = [var] FROM @foo WHERE varname = N'bob';
PRINT @var;
```

Will `@var` be 1 or 3? Who knows? Why does it matter which one it is if you're only capturing one of potentially many values? Are you going to do something with that row but not the others?

In addition, if your intention is to insert data from this table, why not simply throw out the up-front check, the row count etc. and just say:

```
INSERT dbo.SomeTable(column1 --,...other columns
  SELECT var --,...other columns
  FROM dbo.varDB
  WHERE varName = @varName;
```

The insert won't happen if the row doesn't exist.

Answer (score 6):

You can set your variable to `NULL` (just to be sure).

If your query returns no rows, @var is still `NULL`.
If it returns one row, `@var` will have a value
If it returns more than one row you will have an exception.

```
SET @var = NULL

SET @var = (SELECT var FROM dbo.varDB WHERE varName = @varName)
IF @var IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
//carry out insert
END
```

**Update**

If you really want to use `@@ROWCOUNT` instead you can assign your value using `select` instead of `set`.

```
SELECT @var = var FROM dbo.varDB WHERE varName = @varName
IF (@@ROWCOUNT > 0)
BEGIN
//carry out insert
END
```

Comment: What if the selected value of `var` happens to be `NULL`?

Comment: @user92546 that's why I think it is safer to combine the insert and select into one operation. But Siva is right, the question needs clarification given all the time people have already spent spinning their wheels over what should be a simple solution.

Comment: If OP wants to do something with a NULL value this will not work.

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like this using `EXISTS`. This will check if at least one record exists for the given value in `@varName` before carrying out your statements enclosed between *BEGIN* and *END*.

*Script*:

```
 IF EXISTS (SELECT var FROM dbo.varDB WHERE varName = @varName)
    BEGIN
         //carry out insert
    END
```

*MSDN Documentation*: [**EXISTS (Transact-SQL)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx)

## Based on comments, update #1:

I don't understand the requirement to know the value. I think you might want to use a COUNT, if you are looking to fetch the count.

```
DECLARE @recordsCount
SELECT @recordsCount = COUNT(var) FROM dbo.varDB WHERE varName = @varName

IF recordsCount > 0 
BEGIN
  // your statements
END
```

## Based on comments, update #2:

If you would like to use the result set itself inside the BEGIN and END, then the question needs more details about how the result set would be used inside the statements. Based on further inputs, may be you won't even need the IF statement. Further details needed to provide a clear solution to your problem.

Comment: How would I then access the result returned from my query inside the IF statement?

Comment: Why do you care what the actual count is? Don't you only care if there is already at least one row or zero rows? If it returned 1, 2, or 3 would you do anything differently?

Comment: I only need to know (a) if a value exists and (b) what the value returned is.

Comment: My question was for the OP. I thought that would be obvious.

Comment: @SimonKiely can you explain why you need to know what `@var` is? Where would you use that in the logic you've shown?

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I don't use it in the logic I have shown. Inside of the BEGIN and END statement in my code above, I have an INSERT statement, with one of the columns being populated by the value returned by the SELECT statement I am running above.

Comment: @Siva: Many thanls for the help. Would your update above not return the count of the value returned rather than the actual value returned by the query (which I what I am after! :))?

Comment: So I will still not be able to access the value that my query has returned! (Which is what I require) :)

Comment: @SimonKiely so what if there are two or more rows that match your where clause, are you expecting `@var` to become an array that contains all of the values?

Comment: @Siva sorry, I will try to be absolutely 100% clear in the future, even though I still think it should have been obvious that my question was not to you. :-\

Comment: @Siva if @var in the original query holds the string `'blat'`, and the intent is to use `@var` in a subsequent `insert`, how does `@recordsCount` help him?

Answer (score 4):

You can select and test the count of returned rows:

```
SELECT @var = var FROM dbo.varDB WHERE varName = @varName
IF (@@ROWCOUNT > 0)
BEGIN
   //carry out insert
END
```

Comment: @p.campbell Not true. Please try this: `declare @x int

select @x = null from someaTable where 1 = 0
print @@rowcount`. Change sometable to your table, obviously.